# Make a class iterable from a property using [Symbol.iterator] as generator function

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

I'm trying to make Month class iterable from a property in the constructor. So I used this[Symbol.iterable] as a generator function inside a constructor scope to be able to use the for...of loop and get access to the sequence of days. I'm following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1Zd0Y7OJuI), but it uses Vanilla JavaScript. The problem is happening in the iterator typing, I don't know what to do. If it works in pure JavaScript, I think it should work in TypeScript using the right typing.

//class Month

```
class Month {
  lang: string;
  name: string;
  number: number;
  year: number;
  numberOfDays: number;
  [Symbol.iterator]: () => Generator<Day, void, undefined>; // here is the problem

  constructor(date = null, lang = 'default') {
    const day = new Day(null, lang);
    const monthsSize = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    this.lang = lang;

    this.name = day.month;
    this.number = day.monthNumber;
    this.year = day.year;
    this.numberOfDays = monthsSize[this.number - 1];

    if (this.number === 2) {
      this.numberOfDays += isLeapYear(day.year) ? 1 : 0;
    }

    this[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
      let number = 1;
      yield this.getDay(number);
      while (number < this.numberOfDays) {
        ++number;
        yield this.getDay(number);
      }
    };
  }

  getDay(day: number) {
    return new Day(new Date(this.year, this.number - 1, day), this.lang);
  }
}

const month = new Month();

for(day of month) {
  console.log(day.Date)
}
```

//other code needed

```
const getWeekNumber = (day: Date) => {
  const firstDayOfTheYear = new Date(day.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
  const pastDaysOfYear =
    (day.getTime() - firstDayOfTheYear.getTime()) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

  return Math.ceil((pastDaysOfYear + firstDayOfTheYear.getDay() + 1) / 7);
};

const isLeapYear = (year: number) =>
  year % 100 === 0 ? year % 400 === 0 : year % 4 === 0;

class Day {
  Date: Date;
  dayOfMonth: number;
  dayNumberOfWeek: number;
  dayNameOfWeek: string;
  dayNameOfWeekShort: string;
  year: number;
  yearShort: number;
  month: string;
  monthNumber: number;
  monthShort: string;
  timestamp: number;
  week: number;

  constructor(day: Date | null = null, lang = 'default') {
    day = day ?? new Date();

    this.Date = day;
    this.dayOfMonth = day.getDate();
    this.dayNumberOfWeek = day.getDay() + 1;
    this.dayNameOfWeek = day.toLocaleString(lang, {
      weekday: 'long',
    });
    this.dayNameOfWeekShort = day.toLocaleString(lang, {
      weekday: 'short',
    });
    this.year = day.getFullYear();
    this.yearShort = Number(day.toLocaleString(lang, { year: '2-digit' }));
    this.month = day.toLocaleString(lang, { month: 'long' });
    this.monthNumber = day.getMonth() + 1;
    this.monthShort = day.toLocaleString(lang, { month: 'short' });
    this.timestamp = day.getTime();
    this.week = getWeekNumber(day);
  }

  get isToday() {
    return this.isEqualTo(new Date());
  }

  isEqualTo(day: Day | Date) {
    day = day instanceof Day ? day.Date : day;

    return (
      day.getDate() === this.dayOfMonth &&
      day.getMonth() === this.monthNumber - 1 &&
      day.getFullYear() === this.year
    );
  }

  format(dateStr: string) {
    return dateStr
      .replace(/\bYYYY\b/, this.year.toString())
      .replace(/\b(YYY|YY)\b/, this.yearShort.toString())
      .replace(/\bWWW\b/, this.week.toString().padStart(2, '0'))
      .replace(/\bW\b/, this.week.toString())
      .replace(/\bMMMM*\b/, this.month)
      .replace(/\bMMMM\b/, this.month)
      .replace(/\bMMM\b/, this.monthShort)
      .replace(/\bMM\b/, this.monthNumber.toString())
      .replace(/\bM\b/, this.monthNumber.toString())
      .replace(/\bDDDD\b/, this.dayNameOfWeek)
      .replace(/\bDD\b/, this.dayOfMonth.toString().padStart(2, '0'))
      .replace(/\bD\b/, this.dayNumberOfWeek.toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After hours searching I found the answer:

```
export class Month implements Iterable<Day> {
  lang: string;
  name: string;
  number: number;
  year: number;
  numberOfDays: number;

  constructor(date = null, lang = 'default') {
    const day = new Day(null, lang);
    const monthsSize = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    this.lang = lang;

    this.name = day.month;
    this.number = day.monthNumber;
    this.year = day.year;
    this.numberOfDays = monthsSize[this.number - 1];

    if (this.number === 2) {
      this.numberOfDays += isLeapYear(day.year) ? 1 : 0;
    }
  }

  *[Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<Day> {
    let number = 1;
    yield this.getDay(number);
    while (number < this.numberOfDays) {
      ++number;
      yield this.getDay(number);
    }
  }

  getDay(day: number) {
    return new Day(new Date(this.year, this.number - 1, day), this.lang);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).